# Whitepoint luminance in Windows Phone 7 Camera

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need to find the luminance of the white point of the camera in windows phone 7.

I need it in standard units like cd/m2.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  Luminance in candles/square meter is an intensity measure.  A monitor emits between 50 and 300 cd/m2, no doubt less on a phone.  You need a photometer.  The white point is only relevant to chromacity.  Completely different units, x and y on the CIE diagram.

Comment: @Hans  From what I have learnt at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394035(v=VS.92).aspx Y value in the YCbCr scheme is the luminance value and it is the ratio with the luminance of the white point. Is there any other way to get the value of luminance in windows phone??